# How to access file system of another phone using bluetooth in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, obex

After pairing with a phone via bluetooth, is it possible to access the sd card contents (like music or images)?

Are there any tutorials or sample code for this?

i see an application named "Bluetooth File Transfer" and want to make another like that i read about bluetooth, bluetooth socket but not found any thing useful how to perform that operation i am researching more if i found i will post here the solution if anyone found soon then please post here.... Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to write a program that runs on an Android phone to do this?

Comment: If you're not asking a programming question you should probably be asking it on http://superuser.com.

Comment: @ Deepak Swami: yes, but only for reference

Comment: hey rock have u did this? means i am also doing this but unable...can u pls provide me help for how to share data via bluetooth...vv thanks in adv.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is possible. But you need to know:

1. Which Bluetooth protocol you want to use? Some of them are here:
          [Bluetooth protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Bluetooth_protocol_stack)
2. How big data you are willing to share between, because if you have big
   data then you need to use some other connection.
3. You need to know
   how to secure data, Bluetooth is very vulnerable.

And you can tell us what you want to do? You are programmer or just asking? If so use link as suggested in your comments.

EDIT:
Here is for example some examples in QT programming language, which I use for developing apps for Android: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/QBluetooth_-_A_Qt_bluetooth_library

Comment: I really don't understand your question. You want to make an application or you don't know how to connect to one and transfer data?

Comment: Then if you are familiar with C++ sintax I would recommend QT programming for Android. You have program called QT Necessitas which is ported QT for android devices. With QT you have variety of options. I mean it is cross-platform tool so you can use it on desktop on android, symbian. everything almost with the same code you wrote. You need something else? Have you seen the links I gave you?

Comment: If you are satisfied with answer please mark it as answer :) if you need something else just ask and we will help you.

Answer (score 0):

There was a way in early 2000s with Ericsson and Siemens phones with OBEX protocol, and a user file system.
In windows XP with Toshiba stack you had to assign a virtual COM port to a bluetooth device, and install the original phone software, with its RS232 interface IO drivers.
After that you could browse your phone using OBEX tools, or as a disk device, it there was a driver.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to open sd-card and phone storage of any phone using android, then you can follow the following method:

1. Open your android settings.
2. Now open bluetooth settings.
3. Activate your bluetooth.
4. Search for devices.
5. Pair the bluetooth device.
6. Now you will be able to see a setting sign on right side of name of bluetooth device.
7. Touch that sign. You will now see a file transfer box then ftp client will open and you can open the other phone's storage.

Comment: Please provide some images or screenshots whenever possible. Thanks.

Comment: Please be more specific. What OS are you using, because there is no such option in Windows. FTP server is not a normal part of an Android mobile in user mode, and not a part of Bluetooth. Well, probably there is a file send protocol, but not browsing. OBEX is a normal part of BT stack.