# Browse file system of Raspberry Pi from android via bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, file-transfer, android-bluetooth, raspberry-pi2

Use Case:

I am working on a project which involves a android phone and Raspberry Pi. Raspberry Pi unit would be planted with sensors in the field and once in a while user would walk around with the phone and try to get the readings from the Raspberry Pi. So the app's responsibility is to get the data and plot the graph.

Design:

I was planning to allow user to select the location of the file once the devices are paired. As of now, identification of available devices, programmatic pairing of devices has been done. But I am unable to navigate the Raspberry Pi's file system from android. How do you achieve that?

Any help would be appreciated. In case you pointing to this [resource](http://i-miss-erin.blogspot.in/2009/12/provide-bluetooth-ftp-profile-in.html), please explain as well (taken from selected answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157720/how-to-access-file-system-of-another-phone-using-bluetooth-in-android)).

Comment: So you can connect your Android device over Bluetooth with  a Raspberry Pi. And then you have an app you wrote on your Android device which communicates with a program you wrote on the Raspberry Pi?. Please tell a bit how the app and the program communicate.

Comment: @greenapps Well, there is a program on Raspberry Pi which writes a file. There is no program on Raspberry Pi, which is communicating with android device. I just need to get that file and plot data with it.

Comment: `which is communicating with android device. I`. You mean `which is communicating with an app on a android device. I`

Comment: With samba you can expose a directory to the outside world. Then you can browse the directory on the other machine. Don't know if this works with bluetooth.

Comment: can you elaborate a little more on how are connecting the two over bluetooth, are you pairing using some application or using stock bluetooth application.

Answer (score 1):

You may deploy a Java application on your Raspberry pi and connect it with your Android app via a bluetooth socket:
[Send data from android bluetooth to PC with bluecove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004087/send-data-from-android-bluetooth-to-pc-with-bluecove)

From there you can execute `File.listRoots()` and create your own remote dir browser.